# Can't access Nginx outside home network

Tags: linux, nginx

So, I set up a Nginx server on a Ubuntu system, I can access directly from my LAN.

I then bought a domain and linked it with my public ip address.
I port forwarded port 80 on my router.

So, this is the weird part, I can access my server by typing my domain in my home network.

But, i've been trying to access it outside my network (my phone's lte) and it does not work.

I know i can connect, because my FTP server works directly fine.

I temporarily disable my local firewall to make sure it wasn't an exceptrion problem, but it was not that.

I don't know what else to try?

my server config file

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/ahtpo.host/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debain.html;

server_name ahtpo.host www.ahtpo.host;

access_log /var/log/nginx/ahtpo.host.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/ahtpo.host.error.log;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

my access.log shows access only from my home's public ip and nothing else. all other attempts fail. My error.log is empty

OpenPortCheckTool says that port 80 is closed, even though i've allowed on my firewall and my router

Comment: Your Ubuntu may have its own firewall besides the one in your router.

Comment: first off all `sudo ufw allow 80` to enable port 80 in ubuntu firewall (normally done per default by nginx), then try pinging your computer ip and see if the computer is available from  outside network like lte (since you said you can access ftp i suppose you can), can you post the detailed error you get on browser, access.log and error.log?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My ISP (Cox) does not allow port 80 traffic on a residential address, so I just changed the port number. Thanks for the help. I know it wasn't a programming question, sorry.